# SSIS Package Deployment Version Description

Tags: ssis

Where can you set the description on a package version?
I woud have added a print screen of the "Package Version" window, but since I'm new, I was not allowed to do that.

Thankx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each package, and project, have a Description property in them which you can edit in Visual Studio/BIDS/SSDT. You are not able to alter them at deployment time.

To edit the project's description, right click on the project and select Properties. From there, it can be found under Common Projects, Project

[image]

Each package's description will be accessible from the Control Flow's property menu. I right click in the background and select properties but there are alternate ways of accessing the menu.

[image]

Note that I have my properties sorted alphabetically (AZ). The default is by type so your listing of properties might be in a different order but they will all be present.

Comment: Thanks, in SSIS it is the "Project version" window instead of "package version". So the description of your first window (Project properties) was the one I had to set.